# Is it be possible to give custom names to the newly created type that is pushed to the end of a tuple type, without affecting other argument names?

Tags: typescript, tuples, namedtuple

Here i have a type that takes a tuple type with a fixed number of parameters, and also includes an array of strings as the final parameter. I want to give the tuple type parameters custom names `a`, `b` instead of the default `args_0`, `args_1`, etc. Additionally, I want to give name `c` for new types added to tuple types:

```
type FParams = [a: string, b: number | undefined];

type Func = (...args: [...FParams, string[]]) => void;

const func: Func = (a, b) => undefined;

func('foo', undefined, ['bar']);
```

As a result of the above code pushing type cussing the argument names to be lost:

```
const func: (args_0: string, args_1: number | undefined, args_2: string[]) => void
```

However, I would like to preserve the type names and add an additional name `c` like this:

```
const func: (a: string, b: number | undefined, c: string[]) => void
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine [labeled tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) so that the labels are preserved:

```
type Func = (...args: [...x: FParams, c: string[]]) => void;
// dummy name ----------> ^^          ^^ <-- name you care about

// type Func = (a: string, b: number | undefined, c: string[]) => void
```

It would be nice if you could write `[...FParams, c: string[]]`, but the rule is currently that tuple elements must either be all *unlabeled* like `[...FParams, string[]]` or all labeled like `[...x: FParams, c: string[]]`.  So in order to get that `c` label in there you're forced to give a useless label to the spread `FParams`.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#52853](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52853) to relax that restriction.  But for now this is how you have to do it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgCgQwE4ILYGcoF4oG0EBcU6wSAlgHYDmANFAEZEUCuq9ESUAPlMxQCYQAZpQj8AugG4AsACg5oSLD4BjbFAAUAOh3Iq6Irh1aAHkXjI06OiqIly1XOPEBKbAD4oANwD2ZfjKyAPRBUPysqCBQFGjQALQJiUmeAHopUBmZWWlQADwJ0bFQID7MUCrI0Aj0pcByciFQitAwquoahMSklLQMTKzsnDx8giIUYjZ23Y6uHt5+-PWyKj4UJFBCquZtOB109G5YniPCogFLmxQqGgDkQj4+N3QnYxN4N-TIN66SQA)